# How to get the formatting of a Cell using Office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am developing an Excel Add-In that extracts the text of cell A1 INCLUDING its format and display the text in its own area. So the add in contains this (see screenshot below):
•   Area to display the formatted text
•   Button to start the extraction
[Please Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyyrl.jpg)

bellow is the code that i am using to get the text

```
function displaySelectedCells() {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
        function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                showNotification('The selected text is:', '"' + result.value + '"');
            } else {
                showNotification('Error', result.error.message);
            }
        });
}
```

The above code is using "CoercionType" as "Text" . I have tried a lot to find the solution to get the text as formatted written in a Sheet Cell. The Response i am getting is plane text only :(  Please help me to solve the probelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Michael Saunder's answer: while you can use `myRange.format.font.load(['bold','color','italic','name','size','underline'])`, this will only get you the font, bold, italic, etc. *if the formatting is consistent within the cell and in the entire range represented by the myRange object*.  Since you're only looking for a single cell's format, it doesn't sound like the latter applies to you (it's only a single cell), but the example image you have shows different words within the cell having different bold, italic, color, and so on.  With the current APIs you will *not* be able to get this information.

It sounds like what you're asking is some sort of HTML or image-like representation of the cell. I encourage you to file this as a suggestion on our UserVoice (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/), along with a description of real-world the use-case that you need this for.

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Is it possible to use openXML javascript api to read the data that i needed as explained above?

Comment: Re. OpenXml:  it is only available for Word in the JavaScript API.  So I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 0):

The object you should look at is called [RangeFont](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangefont), which is accessed as Range.format.font. Code:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var myRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    var myFont = myRange.format.font;
    myFont.load(['bold','color','italic','name','size','underline']);
    myRange.load('values');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        log(myFont.color);
        log(myFont.bold);
        log(myRange.values);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For future users - [Range.getCellProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-1.11#getcellproperties-cellpropertiesloadoptions-) loads a 2D array of cell properties